# configure line for openldap

Tags: windows, gcc, windows-xp, openldap

I’m using the command prompt in Windows XP to run this line for OpenLDAP.

I’ve gone to the directory containing the configure file, but when I input `./configure`, it gives me

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

When I input `gcc ./configure` it gives me

> ./configure:file not recognized:file format not recognized collect2:id returned 1 exit status.

Can somebody help me understand these errors?

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX environments:

```
./configure
```

Would run the 'configure' script in the current directory '.'.

In windows, a slash ('/') is usually used as a switch delimiter, rather than a directory specifier, in windows you need to use a backslash ('\').  The reason you're getting your first error, is because windows is trying to invoke '.', which is a directory and pass it the arguments '/configure'.

It's possible, that you may be able to solve your problem by running:

```
.\configure
```

However, this may fail because windows doesn't know what type of application to use to run 'configure', since it doesn't have an extension (although it may be an executable, I don't know).

When you try passing configure to gcc, you're getting an error because configure isn't a source file, it's usually a script of somekind or other, although it may be a binary, I've not used openldap.

What do the first 5 lines of the configure file contain?  Does the configure file have an extension?

Answer (score 0):

there is no mention of Cygwin in your question - so I suspect you are a long way away from getting this to work.  (weeks/months/years)

I suggest this:
http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx

it's not the latest - but it's got everything you'll need.